# Вылетает при смене ориентации экрана unity android

Tags: java, android, c#, unity3d

Приложение на Unity стало вылетать на телефоне при повороте экрана. 
Решил сделать в приложении Landscape(пробовал и left и right)
Теперь ситуация следующая - если телефон сразу лежит на боку - приложение не запускается. 
Если телефон в портретном положении - при запуске приложения оно его поворачивает 
и приложение снова вылетает.

Т.е. единственный выход сразу держать телефон в портретном положении. Вылетает
именно в момент попытки поворота экрана.

Что это может быть и как с этим бороться? 
Unity5

Обновляю проблему. Выяснил, что удаляя плагин Vibrate, проблема исчезает. Возможно, какой то конфликт.
Ссылка на плагин 
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/16648

Может что то в коде там надо подправить

Код манифеста плагина(при удалении строчки с orientation - ничего не меняется)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.izaron.androideffects.vibration"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:icon="@drawable/app_icon">
 <activity android:name="com.izaron.androideffects.vibration.MyMainActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Код класса VibrationActivity

```
 public static class VibrationActivity
{
#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
public static AndroidJavaClass activityClass = new     AndroidJavaClass("com.izaron.androideffects.vibration.MyMainActivity");
public static AndroidJavaClass unityActivityClass = new     AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
public static AndroidJavaObject activityObj =    unityActivityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
#else
    public static AndroidJavaClass activityClass;
public static AndroidJavaClass unityActivityClass;
public static AndroidJavaObject activityObj;
#endif
}
```

Код класса Vibration

```
public static class Vibration
{
#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
private static AndroidJavaObject vibrationObj =      VibrationActivity.activityObj.Get<AndroidJavaObject>("vibration");
#else
  private static AndroidJavaObject vibrationObj;
#endif

public static void Vibrate()
{
    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
        vibrationObj.Call("vibrate");
}

public static void Vibrate(long milliseconds)
{
    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
        vibrationObj.Call("vibrate", milliseconds);
}

public static void Vibrate(long[] pattern, int repeat)
{
    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
        vibrationObj.Call("vibrate", pattern, repeat);
}

public static bool HasVibrator()
{
    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
        return vibrationObj.Call<bool>("hasVibrator");
    else
        return false;
}

public static void Cancel()
{
    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
        vibrationObj.Call("cancel");
}
}
```

Еще в плагина Jar файл весом в 500 кб

Буду также рад предложению альтернативы в данном случае. Встроенный метод 
Hanheld.Vibrate в Unity очень слаб. (включает-выключает и всё)
Может плагин или кусок кода который позволят хорошо управлять вибрацией, как минимум менять её продолжительность.

Через некоторое время проект вообще перестал отправляться на телефон - Unable convert to dex-classes

Стал выдавать вот что

```
       CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.  See                    the Console for details.
         C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_92\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -                    Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/user/Android/sdk\tools" -                  Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program   Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

    stderr[
     Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: alr            eady added: Lcom/unity3d/player/NativeLoader;
     Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already  added: Lcom/unity3d/player/ReflectionHelper;
   Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/unity3d/player/ReflectionHelper$1;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already  added: Lcom/unity3d/player/ReflectionHelper$a;
   Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already  added: Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;
  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$1;
   Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$10;
  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$11;
    Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$12;

   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:608)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.jav a:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:129)
   Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:600)
    ... 9 more


  ]
   stdout[
 processing archive bin\classes.jar...
processing bitter/jnibridge/JNIBridge.class...
processing bitter/jnibridge/JNIBridge$a.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/NativeLoader.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/ReflectionHelper.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/ReflectionHelper$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/ReflectionHelper$a.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$10.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$11.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$12.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$13.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$14.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$15.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$15$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$16.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$17.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$18.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$19.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$20.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$3.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$4.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$5.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$6.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$7.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$8.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$9.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$a.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$b.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$c.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayerActivity.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayerNativeActivity.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayerProxyActivity.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityWebRequest.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/WWW.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/a.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/a$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/a$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/a$a.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/b.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/b$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/b$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/c.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/d.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/d$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/d$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/e.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/f.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/g.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/h.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/i.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/j.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/k.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/k$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/k$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/k$2$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/k$2$1$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/l.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/l$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/m.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/n.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/n$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/o.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/p.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/p$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/q.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/r.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/s.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/s$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/s$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/s$3.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/t.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/u.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/v.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/w.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/w$1.class...
processing org/fmod/FMODAudioDevice.class...
processing org/fmod/a.class...
processing archive plugins\.\Vibration.jar...
ignored resource .classpath
ignored resource .project
ignored resource AndroidManifest.xml
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource bin/AndroidManifest.xml
ignored resource bin/R.txt
ignored resource bin/jarlist.cache
ignored resource bin/res/crunch/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png
ignored resource bin/res/crunch/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png
ignored resource bin/res/crunch/drawable-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png
ignored resource bin/res/crunch/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png
ignored resource bin/vibration.jar
processing com/izaron/androideffects/vibration/BuildConfig.class...
processing com/izaron/androideffects/vibration/MyMainActivity.class...
processing com/izaron/androideffects/vibration/R.class...
processing com/izaron/androideffects/vibration/R$attr.class...
processing com/izaron/androideffects/vibration/R$dimen.class...
processing com/izaron/androideffects/vibration/R$drawable.class...
processing com/izaron/androideffects/vibration/R$id.class...
processing com/izaron/androideffects/vibration/R$layout.class...
processing com/izaron/androideffects/vibration/R$menu.class...
processing com/izaron/androideffects/vibration/R$string.class...
processing com/izaron/androideffects/vibration/R$style.class...
processing com/izaron/androideffects/vibration/Vibration.class...
ignored resource ic_launcher-web.png
ignored resource libs/android-support-v4.jar
ignored resource libs/classes.jar
ignored resource proguard-project.txt
ignored resource project.properties
ignored resource res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png
ignored resource res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png
ignored resource res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png
ignored resource res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png
ignored resource res/layout/activity_my_main.xml
ignored resource res/menu/my_main.xml
ignored resource res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml
ignored resource res/values-sw720dp-land/dimens.xml
ignored resource res/values-v11/styles.xml
ignored resource res/values-v14/styles.xml
ignored resource res/values/dimens.xml
ignored resource res/values/strings.xml
ignored resource res/values/styles.xml
processing archive plugins\.\classes.jar...
processing com/unity3d/player/NativeLoader.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/ReflectionHelper.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/ReflectionHelper$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/ReflectionHelper$a.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$10.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$11.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$12.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$12$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$13.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$14.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$15.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$16.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$17.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$18.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$19.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$3.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$4.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$5.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$6.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$7.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$8.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$9.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$a.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$b.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayerActivity.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayerNativeActivity.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayerProxyActivity.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/WWW.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/a.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/a$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/a$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/a$a.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/b.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/b$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/b$2.class...
 processing com/unity3d/player/c.class...
 processing com/unity3d/player/d.class...
 processing com/unity3d/player/d$1.class...
 processing com/unity3d/player/d$2.class...
 processing com/unity3d/player/e.class...
 processing com/unity3d/player/f.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/g.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/h.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/i.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/j.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/j$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/k.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/l.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/m.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/m$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/m$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/m$3.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/n.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/o.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/p.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/q.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/q$1.class...
processing org/fmod/FMODAudioDevice.class...
processing org/fmod/FMODAudioDevice$a.class...
processing org/fmod/a.class...
]


 UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi,              UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,             System.String errorMsg)
   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String          javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32    memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit    waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
 UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe,     System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB,   System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit    waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
  UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

По прежнему актуальным остаётся вопрос - может есть у кого нибудь лучшее решение для вибрации, нежели этот полурабочий плагин

Comment: А можно к вопросу прикрепить stack trace исключения?

Comment: @VladD Прошу прощения, а как его сделать на телефоне? В других условиях проблема не воспроизводится.

Comment: Ну, запустите под отладчиком, должно сработать.

Comment: @VladD Через некоторое время он вообще перестал запускаться с этим плагином. Выдает вот что (текст большой, добавил в основной пост)